# EmailMessage Data Storage Isuue in Production

Tags: servicecloud, emailmessage, data-storage

Currently we are facing storage issue in the production org. EmailMessage has consumed most of the data storage there.
As of now we don't want to store the old data to another storage as client need this data.We are looking for a diff solution for reducing the EmailMessage storage by processing old data.
As we are thinking to convert html emails to plain text but this can be processed on new emails not the existing one as we have restrictions from salesforce that we can not perform update operataion on EmailMessage.

Is there any way I can get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would probably contact Salesforce support or have the client contact their AE.  I don't think there's really any workaround with regards to storage if you truly need the records there other than increasing your limit.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create new plain text templates from scratch and there is no way of converting existing HTML email templates to plain text.  Check if you can clean up un-necessary data ([record size](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318951&type=1&mode=1)) manually or use [Storage Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5fvwEAB).

If you do not want to clean up your data then you will need to purchase [Data Storage](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334051&type=1&mode=1).

Thanks